# How do I prevent a windows invalid file name from getting renamed when opening in VS Code in the windows linux subsystem?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to work on a repo that has a bunch of file with names like xxx:abc.js. Obviously the colon in the file name is invalid in windows.

So I thought if the files were on the Linux subsystem in Windows and if I was using VS Code's Remote extension, then it would be like I was developing in a Linux environment.

But the colon in those file names is still getting automatically removed by git when the repo gets opened by doing `code .`

Do I need to actually install the linux version of VS Code on ubuntu or is there some other way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to WSL 2, cloned the repo again and didn't have any issues.